# Postman - Picking random values from excel file

Tags: postman, web-api-testing

I am testing an API, that the endpoint GET URL contains the following query parameter:

**pairs=EURUSD,GBPJPY**

However these currency pairs (EURUSD and GBPJPY) are only two of the 700 available.
I have stored them in an excel file and I am wondering if I could parse this file in the Pre-request Script and randomly pick 2 of them (randomly picking 2 cells of the postman) in order to validate a different couple of currencies in every API call

Any clue whether is it possible or not, please ?

//Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using CSV and JSON data files in the Postman Collection Runner is already available:

http://blog.getpostman.com/2014/10/28/using-csv-and-json-files-in-the-postman-collection-runner/

You could pick random values if you generated the CSV/JSON file from a GET call issued previously.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! That's it what I was looking for

Comment: There is a checkbox to the left. Ticking it gives you a few rep points and lets everyone know this problem is sorted.